# ip not rejected - iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I was trying to reject a specific IP from connecting to my web server, so I used the following command:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -s 65.55.44.100 -j DROP
# service iptables save
```

After killing all httpd processes and restarting httpd, the IP is still showing up in netstat in the follwing format:

```
::ffff:65.55.44.100:port
```

Shouldn't the new iptable rule deny this IP from connecting?

Answer (score 0):

That is IPv6 and it is managed via ip6tables.

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -s ::ffff:65.55.44.100 -j DROP
```